# Rails 5 - Understanding the new action and rendering errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

My questions is regarding section 5.10 of the official [Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

I have an **articles** model with fields **Title** and **Text**

**article.rb** :

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

**articles_controller.rb** :

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
end
```

The guide says that

> @article = Article.new

needs to be added to the **new** action otherwise otherwise @article would be nil in our view, and calling `@article.errors.any?` would throw an error. Here is the **new.html.erb** :

```
<%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>

  <% if @article.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@article.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
        this article from being saved:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :title %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.label :text %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

What I am able to understand is when there is an error, it is present in @articles so @article.errors.any? helps in showing the errors when the 'new' view is rendered. It indeed works as expected but what I am not able to understand is `@article = Article.new` in the new action should reset the @article and the errors should be lost after the user is redirected to `new`. But somehow, the errors are not lost and are indeed being displayed. How is this happening ?

Comment: `render' and `redirect` both are different in case of errors we use `render` to the new form action. Please read [render vs redirect](https://tosbourn.com/difference-between-redirect-render-rails/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `render` and `redirect` are different things.

1. `render` Renders the content that will be returned to the browser as the response body.
2. `redirect` or `redirect_to` - Redirect is concerned about telling the browser it needs to make a new request to a different location or to the same location as given in path.

It is clearly mentioned in [artcle 5.10](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-some-validation)

> Notice that inside the create action we use render instead of redirect_to when save returns false. The render method is used so that the @article object is passed back to the new template when it is rendered. This rendering is done within the same request as the form submission, whereas the redirect_to will tell the browser to issue another request.

**Note:** You can read [render vs redirect](https://tosbourn.com/difference-between-redirect-render-rails/) in detail

As per your question

```
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new' # this will add  error (validations) 
    end
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      redirect_to 'new' # this will not add any error as this is new request and @article will initialise again.
      new #same as redirect
    end
  end
```

**Edit**: Creating Form Objects with ActiveModel. A form object is an object designed specifically to be passed to form_for

We always check for errors `@article.errors.any?` it will execute if `@article` object contains any error messages

Please read [form_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) doc.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying render won't execute anything under 'new'. I though it would. Then why do we need declare @article in 'new' ? Just so when we hit 'new' for the first time and the .errors dont break ? Is there any better solution ?

Comment: Because form_for needs an object. so we create `@article = Article.new`

Comment: "Because form_for needs an object. so we create @article = Article.new" - i think you are not correct here. If you see section 5.8, 'new' action is empty and error is not implemented yet and still form submission works.

Comment: It is one of the reason. I added this as per your question.

Comment: Because you do not have any validations there. default when any form submits it will redirect to its create action. and `error.any?` and in `@article = Article.new` we initialise a model instance. Validation are added in `5.10`

Comment: @ts The form isn't using the @article object, it is `form for :article`. The object is only needed for the errors block to make the page reusable by both methods.

Comment: @Matt Yes , ActiveModel object is only used to add errors in case of new. If we do not want any error we can use `:article` with `form_for` as OP is using

Answer (score 1):

`render` doesn't run any code in the `new` method, it just uses the `new.html.x` view. As such, `@article = Article.new` is never executed.

If you wanted the code from `new` run, you would need to actually call that method:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

  if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    new #actually runs the code in the 'new' method
    render 'new' # doesn't go anywhere near the new method, just uses its view
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying render won't execute anything under 'new'. I though it would. Then why do we need declare @article in 'new' ? Just so when we hit 'new' for the first time and the .errors dont break ? Is there any better solution ?

Comment: In your case I think you define a fresh instance of article so that the form has an object when it checks for errors. Technically you only need this because you are re-using the view for the create method as well. If that errors block wasn't in there, `new` wouldn't need to define a fresh object, but `create` would need its own view so that it could show errors. Compare the two aproaches and `@article = Article.new` is a small cost for dry views. You could alternatively check whether @article exists before handling errors, and remove it from `new`.